# Generic printing driver for android?

Tags: android, printing

I'am trying to print a document through Bluetooth or Wifi, and I found this could be done using Kitkat (API 19) and later only.

For the older versions you will need to include the printer driver, is that correct? or there is a generic driver that works on most printers for older versions of android?